# show only one popover at a time on state change

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

```
I want to show different popovers on different listitems using reactstrap but on state change the property of popover become true and show all popovers are displayed rather than just one that i clicked.
//setting popoveropen:false initially
 this.state = {
      popoverOpen: false
    };
//on click this toggle function runs which change the popoverOpen state to true which displays all the popover
toggle() {
    this.setState({
      popoverOpen: !this.state.popoverOpen
    })
  }
```

//this is the jsx section where i have used popovers in list items on click of which the toggle function runs and change the popoverOpen State to true
        render(){
        return(
            
                Members
                        Popover Title
                        body1

```
            <ListGroupItem tag="button" id="Popover2" onClick= 
             {this.toggle2}>Labels<Popover placement="left" isOpen= 
              {this.state.popoverOpen} 
              target="Popover2" toggle={this.toggle}>
               <PopoverHeader>Popover Title</PopoverHeader>
                <PopoverBody>body2</PopoverBody>
              </Popover>
             </ListGroupItem>
          </ListGroup>)}
just logic is missing in this code
```

Comment: what are `toggle` and `toggle2` functions?

Comment: oh sorry both were toggle but i was trying some stuff that's why it's got changed.
but still these won't work
I have solved it by creating a different component for the popover and passing differrent props on the different element click by doing this each element has a separate state